# unary function with named destructuring

Tags: javascript, arrays, destructuring

I wondered if you could consider a function like this an unary function:

```
function unaryOrNot([foo,bar,baz,...args,]){}
```

with an input like

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Technically there is only one input, but I do still have named access to foo, bar and baz, the first three properities of the array.

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: What's the difference wether you *consider* it unary or not? What's the question behind this question?

Comment: I am mostly just curious. I was thinking about some edge cases while dealing with function shapes. And wasn't able to recognize the correct solution for this example.

Answer (score 1):

The function is unary, the function takes only a single argument.

If this makes it more clear to you, you could also write the function as:

```
function unaryOrNot(arg0) {
  const [foo,bar,baz,...args,] = arg0;
  //...
}
```

Wether you destructure the value that is passed to the function or not is irrelephant; it doesn't change the function signature.

you could even write

```
function unaryOrNot() {
  const [foo,bar,baz,...args,] = arguments[0];
  //...
}
```

if you dare submit this to a code-review. *(I dare you ;))*

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I will give my best to use ``arguments`` as often as possible ;)